# display a flash message with events with vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to do what is [here](https://github.com/laracasts/Lets-Build-a-Forum-in-Laravel/commit/5f1b80a2458fd1981a1d8d28674a452e91b47783) in the source code, but it is not working.

But event is sent but never received.

Here is the simplest example I could make:

in bootstrap.js:

```
window.events = new Vue();

window.flash = function (message, level = 'success') {
    console.log('emit'); // This is working
    window.events.$emit('flash', { message, level });
};

Vue.component('flash', require('./vue/components/Flash.vue'));
```

Flash.vue:

```
<template>
    <div> MY FLASH</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        created() {
            window.events.$on(
                'flash', data => alert('event!!!')
            );
        },
    };
</script>
```

and in my view:

```
<flash></flash>
```

I can see in my view the component rendering ie MY FLASH message, but I never get the alert coming from emit!

I also have no error in debugger

Am I missing something? it seems quite simple....

Comment: Are you calling `flash()` somewhere?

Comment: right now, I simplified it to find the bug, I don't call flash(), I just call alert('event') to know if it is triggered. What I know if `window.events.$emit('flash');` has been called, but never received

Comment: ok, so where should I call it? In any  vue component???

Comment: So, you know, somewhere that the `console.log('emit')` is fired?

Comment: mmm let me check, I will give it a try quickly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in your question sets up a global function called `flash` that triggers the event. That function has to be called *somewhere* in order for the event to be triggered.

Here is [a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/m527rwqo28) that demonstrates. Everything except triggering the event is from your code.

Note that the alert will only show if the `flash` method is called *after* the Flash component is created.

Also, remember when using a bus to *remove* the listener when the component is destroyed to prevent adding multiple listeners if the component is created more than once.

Comment: yes, it is working....  what I don't understand is why do I need to call a flash() method if I already had `    console.log('emit'); // This is working
` working??? I will read again vuejs docs :) Thanks!

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro It's possible that you *are* calling `flash` somewhere but it is being called *before* the Flash.vue component is created. If that were the case, then the console would emit the output, but the alert would not be shown.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I fall in the same situation, my solution maybe is not the best but is working for me.

Based in this response "Note that the alert will only show if the flash method is called after the Flash component is created." by Bert.

The flash component may have a few uses cases, if you want to use in the same view/page it will be fine, because the component is mounted and still any event hasn't been fired. But if you wan to use in a view/page transition using vue router, you will need to use vuex to store your alert message and then fetch and display the alert.
[image: Sample]